# TFS 2015: unable to create service hooks only on a specific project

Tags: service, tfs, hook

I have an issue with a user that is a Collection Administrator, and is able to create a Service Hook subscription on all Projects, except one that was created before he became Collection Administration.
Is this normal?

There is a way to assign this permission on this project?

Answer (score 0):

To set up a subscription the user needs `Edit subscriptions` and `View subscriptions` permissions.

By default, only project administrators have these permissions. You can use use `tfssecurity.exe` from the command line to grant them to other users for the specific project. See [Change groups and permissions with TFSSecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd) for details.

By default this server-level tool is located in Drive: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Tools` on the TFS application-tier server.

For example:

```
tfssecurity /a+ /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection ServiceHooks PublisherSecurity/abcdef00-abcd-0000-0000-abcdef000000 ViewSubscriptions n:username ALLOW
```

And

```
tfssecurity /a+ /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection ServiceHooks PublisherSecurity/abcdef00-abcd-0000-0000-abcdef000000 EditSubscriptions n:username ALLOW
```

The GUID is the ID of the team project. You can get it using the [Projects REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#get-a-team-project).

Comment: @magnum Have you resolved the issue by above answer? any update?